# What's the relationship between Promise、Promises、Promises/A、Promises/A+?

Tags: javascript

when i learn ES6 Promise，i am confused by the relationship between these

- [Promises](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises)
- [Promises/A](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises/A)
- [Promises/B](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises/B)
- Promises/KISS
- Promises/C
- Promises/D
- [Promises/A+](https://promisesaplus.com/)

Comment: Whoa, I didn’t know all of those existed. ES promises are the ones that actually matter nowadays, though, and Promises/A+ is a good approximation for them that’s easier to read.

Comment: Never seen anything other than a plain old JavaScript promise used.